# Partition aligned index is causing high CPU on SQL Server after updating statistics

Tags: sql-server, indexing, cpu-usage, partitioning, database-performance

I have some dodgy scenario on SQL Server and wonder if someone can help with or point me into correct direction... the story is below:

1. We have table with 264 partitions on it. All indexes are partition aligned.
2. We are adding another index, also partition aligned, this is to support query not used yet.
3. Everything seems to be working fine for another 20+ hours, until update statistic job kicks off...
4. When the job kicks off we observe increased CPU usage on existing queries which are not using this index at all. Query plans stays the same, just server goes mad and seems to be burning cpu for nothing.
5. Newly added index doesn't seem to be used at all. No reads, no lookups, it's just there and seems to be eating our CPU.
6. After dropping this new index - all immediately calms down and CPU is back to normal.

Did anyone have similar issue? What should we possibly check? EBS volumes are not showing increased read/write during CPU spike so it probably suggests some problems with inserting records... index fragmentation is one of our theories... however why update stats would kill other queries performance?

Hope you will find that issue interesting...

Comment: Partition aligned or no, I'd expect that that the new index is being used by *something*. How did you validate that nothing was using it?

Comment: Are you sure it's the new index? You mentioned you're updating your statistics which would absolutely slow the show for a little while (and could even be causing you parameter sniffing issues) until those statistics caught back up.

Comment: We are using sp_blitzindex to determine if it was used... nothing there.

Comment: Everything points to new index. Execution plans are staying the same for all the queries we are running after update stats, so no parameter sniffing issue I think. Seems that inserts to the table are being much slower after stats update.

Comment: We've played scenario with index fill factor set to 70. Immediately after index creation cpu spiked to 90%....so it's not update stats causing it... unless we don't understand something...